# Retrieve an element by XPath/CSS from HTML

Tags: webdriver

I am trying retrieve an element "Nature News Standard Article in Nature News & Comment" which is part of below HMTL code.

I have following WebDriver code in selenium:

```
if ("Polopoly CM".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
    System.out.println("----> Title of page  <----");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'nav_') and @class='p_textOutput']"));
System.out.println("----> Xpath Selected  <----");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'nav_') and @class='p_textOutput']")).click();
  System.out.println("----> Xpath Clicked <----");
```

}

***Problem is: i am unable to retrive the required element through Xpath/CSS from HTML***

HTML:

```
<document>
<html xmlns:polopoly="http://www.polopoly.com/polopoly/cm/app/gui" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="cursor: default;">
<head>
<body id="nav_3" class="navFrameBody" onbeforeunload="busyCursor();" onload="onLoad(); idleCursor();">
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Jasmine.createFrame('nav'); //--> </script>
<form id="mainform" name="mainform" method="post" action="CM">
<input type="hidden" value="2852906396" name="owid"/>**
<input type="hidden" value="1332852912984" name="ofid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="nav" name="ofn"/>
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="ofs"/>
<input id="nav_1" type="hidden" value="0" name="nav_1"/>
<input id="nav_2" type="hidden" value="0" name="nav_2"/>
<div id="nav_13_placeHolder" class="ajax_placeHolder">
<fieldset id="nav_14" class="field"/>
<div id="nav_4" class="p-group quickCreator expanded">
<div id="nav_4_state">
<input id="nav_15" type="hidden" value="expanded" name="nav_15"/>
</div>
<div class="toggleIcon clearfix"/>
<script lang="javascript">$(document).ready(function() {p_makeExpandable('nav_4', 'nav_15')});</script>
<fieldset id="nav_16" class="contentCreator field topContentCreator">
<div class="quickCreator contentCreator container">
<div class="quickCreator header clearfix">
<h2> Create New </h2>
<a id="nav_17" class="customize" href="javascript:actionEventData({$contentId:"18.232.1319560059", $action:"edit", $target:"work", $opentab:"menu/quickCreatorLayout"})">Customize</a>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="quickCreator link">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="nav_18"/>
<a id="nav_18" href="javascript:submitForm(document.mainform, document.mainform.nav_18, "x")">
<img id="nav_19" class="centered" alt="" src="images/icons/transparentIcon.png"/>
<span id="nav_20" class="p_textOutput">Nature News Standard Article in Nature News & Comment</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div id="nav_5" class="p-group contentTree expanded">
<div id="nav_5_state">
<input id="nav_21" type="hidden" value="expanded" name="nav_21"/>
</div>
<div class="toggleIcon clearfix"/>
<script lang="javascript">$(document).ready(function() {p_makeExpandable('nav_5', 'nav_21')});</script>
<div class="field contentTree">
<div id="nav_6_placeHolder" class="ajax_placeHolder">
<div class="header">
<span class="label">Content Tree</span>
<button id="nav_9" type="button" value="Refresh tree" name="nav_9">
<img id="nav_22" class="centered" alt="" src="images/icons/refresh.png"/>
<span id="nav_23" class="p_textOutput"> Refresh tree</span>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- jQuery(document).ready(function() { addOnClickEvent("nav_9",null, "nav_9_placeHolder", null, new IndicatorLifecycleHook('p.std_ajaxIndicator', true, 0.8, "createImageTop('images/ajax/busy_indicator_big_green.gif')"));  }); //--> </script>
</button>
</div>
<div class="tree">
<div id="nav_8_placeHolder" class="ajax_placeHolder">
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.require(["script/polopoly-ui.js"]); </script>
<input id="nav_8" type="hidden" value="" name="nav_8"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.require(["script/polopoly-ui.js"]); </script>
<ul id="nav_8_tree" class="tree">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<fieldset id="nav_24" class="field clipboard">
<input id="nav_25" type="hidden" value="" name="nav_25"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- jQuery(document).ready(function() { if(window.parent.SeleniumPageLoadCountnav==null) { window.parent.SeleniumPageLoadCountnav=1; window.parent.SeleniumPageLoadCountnavOld=0; } else { window.parent.SeleniumPageLoadCountnav+=1; } }); //--> </script>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your behaviour, but had no luck. The xpath expression returns me the right element. Which browser do you use, what does it mean "I am unable to retrieve"? Does the webdriver throw NoSuchElementException?
By the way, the given html code doesn't have "Polopoly CM" as a title, which means your code is not executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I see two elements which can be selected by your xpath locator. Try to find both of them.

```
List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("your_xpath"));
for (Element element : elements) {
    element.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is:
Nature News Standard Article in Nature News & Comment

So, You can use id or xpath to retrieve the element text as follows:

Using id:

```
String s = driver.findElement(By.id("nav_20")).getText();
System.out.println(s);
```

Using xpath:

```
String s1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='nav_20']")).getText();
System.out.println(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

css=a[href*='javascript:submitForm'] > span.p_textOutput

Try the above CSS Selector. I am sure it will work out.

Please Let me know is it working or NOT.